# Validation error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, frontend and user with respective controllers and views.

From a `form_for` in frontend view I'm calling a create method in user controller and I save new user in database. All works.

The problem comes with validation.
If something is wrong with  the model validators I need error messages to be displayed on frontend view... so, I need that if there are errors, when I `redirect_to` frontend (since render seems not possible for different controller) is possible to display errors here.

I haven't found solutions for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I may, you are going about it wrong.  cite has the right idea with doing a render partial.

Let's say that you are calling your frontend from the root of the application, with the registration page all laid out there.  In the controller method that has this view, create an instance variable of your user that is then used in the form.  For example...

```
def some_method_for_the_root
    @user = User.new
end
```

Then in your view

```
all your code for the view
render :partial => '/users/new'
```

Within that partial, have your form_for the @user object.  Voila, you have a user object that can be used on your main app, and then if the validation fails, it would be best to either update via ajax, or direct the user to a page to explicitly show them the errors.

This is all just from my experience, but it's generally the method I have seen done most often.

Comment: Yes, I solved with partials.. Now I need to find a way to handle validation errors via ajax.. in pure "rails way of life" :) . Thanks!!

Comment: Ok, I've tried adding a nice commented response twice already, and it hates me.  So, see my other answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you use redirect_to, the validation information on that particular object will get lost. You can try playing cheap shots with saving the object in the flash or the session, retrieving it in the frontend controller (creating an instance variable) and have it validated again, so that the `error_messages` helper has something to work with.

OTOH, that approach seems flawed. Why not create the form for a new user in the user controller?

Comment: Yes, it seems a bit too cumbersome ;) .
I'm not create the form in the user controller because in one of my frontend view I need a small form for user registration. If I'm wrong approaches, I listen!

Comment: Put the HTML/ruby code for that form in a partial - you can render partials from a view not belonging to the current controller at any time by simply calling render => "viewname/partial".

Comment: In this way, however, renders only the partial, frontend view isn't showed!

Comment: Ok, maybe I found. I indicated "viewname" explicitly for the other partial I've used, because it passes control to user (unfortunately).
Now to make it all work,my poor frontend view is composed of only a render: partial => "blabla", other things are finished inside the partial.. But it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple again, in itself. With the method that your form_for calls, let's say it's called def create (within your users controller).

```
def create @user = User.new(params[:user])
 @user.save
 if !@user.errors.empty?
   @failed = true
 end
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js {} # Will render the create.js.rjs file
 end
end

##### create.js.rjs #####

if @failed
 display the errors
else
 do whatever you wish here
end
```